# how to check for some character in the string?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

i have a string..

I am entering some characters from user using that string.

Now i want to check that in that string "a" is there or not?

can anyone tell me how to do this?

that "a" can be anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ([myString rangeOfString:@"a"].location != NSNotFound) {
  // "a" IS in myString
} else {
  // "a" ISN'T in myString
}

if ([myString rangeOfString:@"a"].location != NSNotFound && [myString rangeOfString:@"b"].location != NSNotFound) {
  // "a" AND "b" are BOTH in myString
} else  if ([myString rangeOfString:@"a"].location != NSNotFound) {
  // ONLY "a" is in myString
} else  if ([myString rangeOfString:@"b"].location != NSNotFound) {
  // ONLY "b" is in myString
} else {
  // Neither "a" NOR "b" is in myString
}
```

Comment: and what if i want to try it for both a and b?? is it like @"a",@"b" ..like that??

Comment: I've updated my post (changed first half as well). Tell me if it doesn't work.

Comment: but still I want to do it like ...i want to check if both a and b is there or not ...if any one of them is there i want to call some method..do u know what to do in such case?

Comment: I would check the ranges location and if its != NSNotFound, according to the reference the length can be anything as its not initialized.

Comment: Okay, I've changed it. I just figured I'd use the length since it was shorter.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)isCharaterExist:(NSString *)sPhrase withSearchChar:(NSString *)sChar {

      NSAssert(sPhrase != nil && sChar != nil, @"sPhrase and sChar should not be nil");

      return ([sPhrase rangeOfString:sChar].length > NSNotFound);
}
```

Note: It's not tested in running environment, so typo mistakes can be possible!